# Cordova date-picker issue

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

picker plugin in cordova [date-picker plugin link](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) . It successfully configure into iOS and android project and its works only first time, after that date function not call again.

```
function dateAction(){
  alert("here");
  datePicker.show(options, function(date){
    alert("date result " + date);
  });
}

var options = {
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date'
};
```

Please figure out the problem. I will use same code which will be provide into that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the options in the function

```
 function dateAction(){

    var options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date'
      };
    alert("here");
    datePicker.show(options, function(date){
        alert("date result " + date);
    });
    }
```

This should work!